# Is there a plastic alternative to expanded metal mesh for replacing a section of rock-lath ceiling?

Tags: plaster, expanded-mesh, rock-lath

In our foyer a section of ~7/8 thickness rock-lath ceiling (sheetrock + sanded plaster basecoat reinforced by expanded mesh + plaster skim-coat) was cut out between the floor joists in conjunction with a bathroom remodel above. To begin to replace that section of ceiling  I've screwed 3/8 sheetrock to the joists. Now I want to put a 3/8" base-coat of perlite plaster over the sheetrock and follow up with a 1/8" skim coat.

But I have nothing but expletives for the task of trying to affix expanded metal mesh to the sheetrock overhead in a one-man-with-only-two-hands scenario, so that the mesh is taut and doesn't sag like a #@(@$&* hammock.

Is there some kind of plastic lattice or honeycomb with sufficient tensile strength so it could be used in place of the expanded metal mesh and give the perlite-plaster base-coat something to "key" into and also provide some structural reinforcement?

EDIT: The expanded metal mesh is not flat. It is cheap stuff from the big box stores that might as well have been sat upon by somebody and stretched out of shape. It needs to be pulled really taut to eliminate the sag and that's almost impossible to do by hand.

Comment: Please clarify/translate the **#@(@$&**

Comment: I would use 2 or more lateral board strips (1/8), to hold the net in place without #@(@$&*

Comment: I do not know what a `lateral board strip` is. Please clarify.  If adding additional thickness the strip would have to be no thicker than 1/16".

Comment: Parallel to the ceiling to temporary hold the #@(@$&

Comment: I understand the principle but do not know the specific item you are referring to.

Comment: pice of wood strips, 1/4 thick 2" wide and as long as you need it, screwed to the ceiling holding the wire mesh in place till you fasten it

Comment: what ever man, take 1/8 or what please you, you will remove it after the mesh was mounted

Comment: The expanded metal mesh is not flat. It is cheap stuff from the big box stores that might was well have been sat upon by somebody and stretched out of shape. It needs to be pulled really *taut* to eliminate the sag, and temporary strips to hold it in place don't make it taut.

Comment: how did you plan to mount it in first lace, with screws or staples or what

Comment: I planned to affix the mesh to the joists (nailing through the sheetrock) with roofing nails, same as the original. I used a crown race stapler to hold in in place but I cannot eliminate the sag because the mesh itself is deformed ("baggy") like an old sock. It is not "in plane".

Comment: find the largest pipe you have and roll it over in one way then in the opposite way to flatten it

Comment: Get mesh that isn't all #@(@$&*ed up! Repairing things with broken parts isn't usually your best bet for a fix.

Comment: Most repairs like that are made with sheetrock brought down, in your case, flush to the ceiling and finished with drywall tape and mud. This is a comment since it does not answer your specific question. If you wish to be the purist and still use plaster and all the associated materials, there are no shortcuts.

Comment: @Jack: The original rock-lath ceiling held up well for 75 years so I thought I'd try to replicate the approach. The ceiling is considerably thicker than drywall, it's just a hair shy of being a full 1" thick. A 10' length of ceiling needs to be replaced. If a 5/8 panel is screwed to the joists there would be ~3/8 thick mud along that entire length. I feared the mud would crack if laid on that thick.

Comment: You can use 1/2" or 5/8" either one works, the trick is adding wood to the joists, either beside it by sistering or custom ripping to thickness to be added to the underside, then add the sheetrock. Everything will line up flush so a thin skim can go over the tape after it is applied. The surface of the plaster will have so many coats of paint over it after so may years, any repair will be detected because of the surface texture, because of this.

Answer (score 1):

They do make a fiberglass version of the classic metal mesh, (example, no affiliation: [FibaLath](https://www.menards.com/main/building-materials/metal-framing/39-x-25-fibalath/flx7207-a/p-1525847276700-c-5695.htm)). However, I think you will have difficulties using it on a ceiling as it probably won't hold its own weight like the metal mesh will - you will have to secure it at many more points. Once your base layer has adhered, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use plywood or MDF instead of sheetrock you can use as many staples as it takes to attach the metal lath sufficiently. (you may want to consider an air or electric powered stapler)

Sheetrock is the second worst construction material available (adobe is worse) if it's giving you grief use something better.

Sure it's flat that's because it comes out of a factory, it's cheap because all you're buying is dried mud wrapped in brown paper (adobe is dried mud not wrapped in paper).

MDF is brown paper all the way through, so superior to sheetrock :)

Comment: But code requires minimum 5/8 thickness of a material that cannot catch fire, if I recall correctly.